# How to get RGB value for the mixed color?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to select a particular color in canvas and get an RGB value for that color.
Can anyone please help me to do this?

Here is the code for [canvas](http://jsfiddle.net/WrEMA/)

```
var c=document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx=c.getContext("2d");
var grd=ctx.createLinearGradient(0,0,200,0);
grd.addColorStop(0,"red");
grd.addColorStop(0.15,"yellow");
grd.addColorStop(0.3,"green");
grd.addColorStop(0.45,"aqua");
grd.addColorStop(0.6,"blue");
grd.addColorStop(0.7,"fuchsia");
grd.addColorStop(1,"red");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With jQuery:

```
// utility function to retrieve click position inside the canvas
function findPos(obj) {
    var curleft = 0, curtop = 0;
    if (obj.offsetParent) {
        do {
            curleft += obj.offsetLeft;
            curtop += obj.offsetTop;
        } while (obj = obj.offsetParent);
        return { x: curleft, y: curtop };
    }
    return undefined;
}

$('#myCanvas').click(function(e) {
    var pos = findPos(this);
    var x = e.pageX - pos.x;
    var y = e.pageY - pos.y;
    var coord = "x=" + x + ", y=" + y;
    var c = this.getContext('2d');
    var p = c.getImageData(x, y, 1, 1).data; // get 1x1 pixels area at the (x,y) position
    var red_value = p[0];
    var green_value = p[1];
    var blue_value = p[2];
});
```